# Indexing in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, indexing, elasticsearch, webrequest

I am having problems indexing in elasticsearch. I have a function which creates an index and another one that creates a type mapping for a json I will be indexing. Both of these work fine but when I try calling the function to index something, it gives me a WebException saying that the remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

This is my code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string endpoint = "http://localhost:9200";
        string index = "logs";
        string type = "activity-log";

        createIndex(endpoint, index);
        createMapping(endpoint, index, type);
        indexEvent(endpoint, index, type);
    }

public static void createIndex(string endpoint, string index)
    {
        //Build request url
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}/", endpoint, index));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";   //set content type of json
        request.Method = "PUT";    //use POST method when creating an index
        string json = "{\"settings\":{\"number_of_shards\":3,\"number_of_replicas\":2}}";
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
        string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //create a web response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
        Console.ReadKey();
        response.Close();
    }

 public static void createMapping(string endpoint, string index, string type)
    {
        //Build request url
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/_mapping", endpoint, index, type));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";   //set content type of json
        request.Method = "PUT";    //use POST method when creating an index
        string json = "{\"activitylogevent\":{\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"parentId\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"event\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"}}}}";
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
        string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //create a web response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
        Console.ReadKey();
        response.Close();
    }

    public static void indexEvent(string endpoint, string index, string type)
    {
        //build the request URL            
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/", endpoint, index, type);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";   //set content type of json
        request.Method = "POST";    //use POST method when indexing a record without specifying id, and PUT when you specify an id

        string jsonEvent = "{\"id\":\"123546789\",\"parentId\":\"abc123\",\"event\":\"CloseAccount\"}";

        byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
        string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //create a web response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("after get response");
        Console.ReadLine();
        StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
        Console.ReadKey();
        response.Close();
    }
```

I was doing something wrong in my createIndex function but here is my working function incase anyone finds it helpful:

```
public static void createIndex(string endpoint, string index)
    {
        //Build request url
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("{0}/{1}/", endpoint, index));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";   //set content type of json
        request.Method = "PUT";    //use PUT method when creating an index
        string json = "{\"settings\":{\"activity-log-events\":{\"number_of_shards\":3,\"number_of_replicas\":2}}}";
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
        string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //create a web response
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim());
        Console.ReadKey();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the elasticsearch log file for clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a some changes to my createIndex function and it worked. I posted the changes above.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one error in your indexEvent() function. You are setting the string jsonEvent but then using an undefined string json when setting up byteData:

```
string jsonEvent = "{\"id\":\"123546789\",\"parentId\":\"abc123\",\"event\":\"CloseAccount\"}";

byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
```

You'll note that you are doing this correctly in the other two functions, using the string json in both places. From createIndex:

```
string json = "{\"settings\":{\"number_of_shards\":3,\"number_of_replicas\":2}}";
byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
```

and from createMapping:

```
string json = "{\"activitylogevent\":{\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"parentId\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"},\"event\":{\"type\":\"string\",\"index\":\"not_analyzed\"}}}}";
byte[] byteData = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(json);
```

There may be other things wrong in the code but that's definitely not going to work.

Comment: Copy and paste error, sorry! Anyways, I was just having a problem in my createIndex function. I posted the changes I made. Thanks!